# I would like to make UITableView cells, entry fields

Tags: iphone

I would like for each of the cells in UITableView be an entry field. In other words when the table appears and a user clicks/taps on a specific cell, the keyboard will appear and what ever the user types gets enter into the field.  I will later use all these field as data in an array, for other uses.

Comment: Make the cells textcells and make them editable.  If you need more than that, you need to post the actual code you're trying to make work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UITextField` to each cell (design a `.xib` file for the cells and [programmatically load the `.xib`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) as part of your table-view implementation). Implement [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), probably the `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method because you might want to validate the input first and not let editing finish until the input is valid. In that method, if input is valid then store it in the array corresponding to what you were talking about. You'll need to do some tricks to find out what row you're currently validating, there's several ways to do it (one of which is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050915/accessing-indexpath-from-custom-uitableviewcell)).

Comment: How do I add a UITextField to each cell? Can you show how this is done?  Will this make the keyboard show, when I tap on the cell? Thank you darvidsOn.

Comment: OK, I don't know what is doing, but this seems to work, I would love to know what these lines of code are actually doing?// Configure the cell...
 UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
 [FirstField setTag:indexPath.row];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
 [FirstField release];

Comment: The `initWithFrame:` sets up the position of the text field relative to the cell (10 pixels from the top, 10 pixels from the left, and a size of 130x25 pixels). The `setTag:` sets an integer identifier tag, which is available on every `UIKit` control, to the row number of the cell in the table. The other two lines are just adding the text field to the cell and then releasing the memory for the text field (because the cell now holds a reference to it).

Comment: Strong darvidsOn, thank you! It works now its time to do more polishing and experimenting with it.